# Singular-Plural agreement

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I am a little bit confused about the use of "each" with the correct noun.  For example, for the use of "each" Which expression is correct?
Each of the previous month or each of the previous months?

Answer (score 1):

...each of the previous month**s** is correct, because you are selecting *from multiple month**s**.* Compare to *...each of the previous five month**s**,* or *...each of the previous twelve month**s**.*

Unless, of course,  this fragment is meant to be possessive. That's another issue altogether.

Comment: My only argument is that I have learned in old grammar school that 'each' always is treated as 'singular' and so the noun following it should be singular as well.

Answer (score 1):

*Months* is correct as Davo mentions.  It might be helpful to think of it this way:

> Each month during the last twelve months...

Your phrase is conveying the same idea in a less specific sense.